# Porque no funciona este codigo en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Porque esto no esta funcionando?

angular.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
});
```

index.html

```html
<div ng-app="adminPanel" ng-controller="adminController">
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
              <td>{{x.name}}</td>
              <td class="right">12</td>
              <td><span class="badge badge-success badge-icon"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>{{x.country}}</span></span></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque tu tag `ng-controller` apunta a otro controlador

Cambia esto :

```
ng-controller="adminController"
```

Por esto

```
ng-controller="namesCtrl"
```

Y tu `ng-app` tambien

Cambia esto :

```
ng-app="adminPanel"
```

Por esto

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

Y tu codigo :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
        <div ng-controller="namesCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td class="right">12</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success badge-icon"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>{{x.country}}</span></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Gracias, se me habia pasado eso en lo que postee, pero tampoco funciona teniendo bien los nombres

Comment: Algun error en consola?

Comment: No, ningun error

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni actualice

Comment: Que actualice que?

Comment: Mi respuesta xd @SantiagoD'Antuoni ahora funciona jeje